# TextWrapping inside a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

## Goal

I have a WPF application that contain text inside a `DataGrid`.
I want the text to wrap inside each cell.
I also want to set a MinWidth for each column and if it has to, the `ScrollViewer` should create the horizonatl scroll bar.
I never want a horizontal scroll bar to appear for the any of the cells or the `DataGrid` itself.
If the user resizes the window, the rows should grow or shrink to accommodate the text wrapping, but it shouldn't allow the coulmns get so thin that they are no longer readable.

## Problem

Right now, the text doesn't wrap because it is in a scrollviewer.
I know of different ways that I can change this sample to get the text to wrap, but I can't get it to act exactly how I want it, as mentioned above.

## Simplified xaml

```
<Window x:Class="SampleApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleApp"
    Title="App" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="WrappingTextBlock" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="WrappingTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Stuff ... />

        <MoreStuff ... />

        <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
            <ScrollViewer>
                <StackPanel>    
                    <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding AwesomeObject, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="5" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="#" Binding="{Binding Number, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header" Binding="{Binding Data, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="50" Header="Long Text" Binding="{Binding SoMuchText, Mode=TwoWay}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource WrappingTextBlock}" EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource WrappingTextBox}"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the Width of the Columns to "*"

```
 <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
     <ScrollViewer>
         <StackPanel>
             <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding AwesomeObject, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="5" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                 <DataGrid.Columns>
                     <DataGridTextColumn Width="10*" Header="#" Binding="{Binding Number, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                     <DataGridTextColumn Width="10*" Header="Header" Binding="{Binding Data, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                     <DataGridTextColumn Width="50*" Header="Long Text" Binding="{Binding SoMuchText, Mode=TwoWay}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource WrappingTextBlock}" EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource WrappingTextBox}"/>
                 </DataGrid.Columns>
             </DataGrid>
         </StackPanel>
     </ScrollViewer>
 </Border>
```

This means that Column 1 will be minimum 10 length and growing
This means that Column 2 will be minimum 10 length and growing
This means that Column 3 will be minimum 50 length and growing

You can play with the * resizing using percentages (.Number*) or lengths (Number*)

Answer (score 2):

You Dont need to put the dataGrid in a scrollViewer... you should set the MAXWidth/Maxheighjt of the DataGrid so that scrollViewr(already present in dataGrid) will appear...... Also if the you wnat to Wrap the Cell text

```
                <WPFToolkit:DataGrid Name="programListDataGrid"
                                     AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                     CanUserAddRows="False"
                                     CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                                     CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                                     IsReadOnly="True"
                                     ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyList}"
                                     RowStyle="{StaticResource ResourceKey=dataGridRowStyle}"
                                     SelectedItem="{Binding Path=MyItem,
                                                            Mode=TwoWay}"
                                     SelectionMode="Single">
                    <WPFToolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
                        <WPFToolkit:DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="100"
                                                       MaxWidth="250"
                                                       Binding="{Binding Path=ItemName}"
                                                       Header="Item Name" />

                        <WPFToolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn                                                                Width="*"
                                                           MinWidth="200"
                                                           Header="ItemData1">
                            <WPFToolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ApplicationPath}"
                                               TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                               ToolTip="{Binding ItemData1}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </WPFToolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </WPFToolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <WPFToolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn                                                                Width="*"
                                                           MinWidth="200"
                                                           Header="ItemData2">
                            <WPFToolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding StandardCLP}"
                                               TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                               ToolTip="{Binding ItemData2}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </WPFToolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </WPFToolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    </WPFToolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
                </WPFToolkit:DataGrid>
```

The `TextBlock` will wrap after the space is consumed... I have not tried this with `ElementStyle` but should work with that too.. All the width and height just for demo you should use your onw values as required... :)

Answer (score 1):

My solution tackles the scenario for when one wishes to have the `Header` text wrap - with control for how wide the column should be too. I use the inbuilt `DataGridTextColumn`, but provide it a custom `HeaderTemplate` in which I control the wrapping of the text:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Axle Group No."/> <!-- this stays with defaults -->
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Axle Group Load Measured :(a)" MaxWidth="100"  ><!-- NOTE: MaxWidth and template below -->
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

If you wish to customizing text wrapping for the data cells too, then it's better you use the fully customizable column type `DataGridTemplateColumn`. That type allows you to specify either the `HeaderTemplate` or the `CellTemplate` in a manner similar to this:

```
<DataGrid>
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn>
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```